# android: add bitmap to another bitmap or increase bitmap size

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap

I need to increase the size of a bitmap in Android, like in this image:

[image]
Basically, the user save the Image1. Then, the user can open again Image1 but I need that the Image2 (that is just a white rectangle) is added to the top of the Image1. So, I need to create another image, that is the Image1 plus another image.
How can I do that?

However, I just need to "increase" the Image1 size, so if there's another way to do that please let me know.

Thanks a lot

Comment: `I need to create another image, that is the Image1 plus another image.` ,Ok.  `I just need to "increase" the Image1 size`. Well that is something completely different. Please decide first what you want.

Comment: What I need is the Image1 plus "something" on top. I thought that it's possible adding an image on top of Image1. For "increase" I mean a result similar to Image1 + Image2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only need the rectangle on top you can do this, but replace drawRect by some drawBitmap if you want to draw another image on top.

```
Bitmap i1 = //load the one
int w = i1.getWidth(), h = i1.getHeight();
Bitmap i3 = Bitmap.createBitmap(i1.getConfig(), w, h + 200); //200 will be the white
Canvas surface = new Canvas(i3);
Paint white = new Paint();
white.setColor(Color.WHITE);
surface.drawRect(0, 0, 200, w, white);
surface.drawBitmap(i1, 0, 200, w, h, white);
```

About increasing height, you can do this with the BitmapConfig.Options, but that will streth the result to match your proportions.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank